# Finding the continuity of a function with parameters

Tags: calculus

> For which values of the parameters $\alpha,\beta$ is the function continuous:
>
> $$f(x)= 
> \begin{cases}\begin{align} 
> &(1+\alpha x)^{\alpha /x} &  x>0 \\ 
> &\beta &x=0 \\
> & e(1+e^{1/x})&x<0 \\ 
> \end{align}\end{cases}   $$

First of all finding the limit of the part without parameters as it goes to zero, it is $e$ because the limit is for $-1<x<0$ which makes $e^{1/x}=0$.

So $\beta=e$.

Now I need to find an $\alpha$ that will make this true: $\lim_{x\to 0^+}(1+\alpha x)^{\alpha /x}=e$.

I thought of turning it into the $e$ identity: $(1+\frac1x)^{x}$. I tried all kind of combinations of positive and negative numbers and fractions with $x$ but nothing seems to work, and now I see now that it won't work since that identity is for $x\to \infty$.

Comment: x→∞ means that 1/x→0, so you can apply the given identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good work on the problem so far. Now, observe that, if we let $y = \frac{1}{x}$, then

$$
(1 + \alpha x)^{\alpha / x} = \left(1 + \frac{\alpha}{y}\right)^{\alpha y}
$$

and as $x \to 0^+$ (since $x > 0$ for this limit), you have $y \to \infty$. So you're almost there. See if you can figure out the rest, otherwise it's in the hint below.

> $\left(1 + \frac{\alpha}{y}\right)^{\alpha y} = \left(\left(1 + \frac{\alpha}{y}\right)^{ y}\right)^\alpha \to \left(e^\alpha\right)^\alpha = e^{\alpha^2}$

Comment: Very nice. Thanks (also for correcting vocab).